# Success message with style, jquery validation

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using [jquery.validation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) following is the code.
I've achieved to show a styled error message by attaching class and giving class some css.

```
$("#sign-up").validate({
    rules: {
        FullName: {
            required: true
        },
        Username: {
            required: true
        },
        Email: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        }
    },
    messages: {
        FullName: "Please enter your full name",
        Username: "Please enter handle name",
        Email: {
            required: "Please enter an email address",
            email: "Please enter a valid email address"
        }
    },
    errorElement: "span",
    wrapper: "div",
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        error.insertBefore(element);
        error.addClass("error-validation");
    }
});
```

But I also want to display a nice looking success message, like error message, styled. Once the validation passes, the message should show.

How can I do this?

Comment: Please read [the documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's in the [documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate)

```
success: function(label) {
  $("#success").show();
},
```

You will need to hide the success before the validation if you do not clear the page

Comment: so, #success should be hidden on page load?

Comment: but that shows only one div, i was going to display separate success messages for each of the fields. is that possible?

Comment: $("#successField1").show();$("#successField2").show();

Answer (score 0):

**Approach 1: (Apply success message to all fields)**

```
 $("#myform").validate({
      success: function(label) {
        label.addClass("valid").text("Ok!")
      }
 });
```

**Approach 2: (Apply success message to specific fields)**

```
   $("#myform").validate({
       errorClass: 'input_msg',
       validClass: "valid",
       unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
           if ($(element).attr('name') == 'email') { /* Apply to email field only */
               $(element).parent().find('.input_msg').addClass(validClass).html('Ok!');
           }
       },
       success: function(label) {},
   });
```

For better understanding have a look at below official link

https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#success